# Resources for building a web protocol

Tags: c++, sockets, http, protocols, tcp

I want to build a transfer protocol on top of TCP to send a certain type of file between two computers. I was wondering if there were any Resources, open source projects or books that I could look at to get an idea of what I should be doing.

Comment: Why not just use HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start would be the W3C [HTTP/1.1 standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/) or the [HTTP/1.0 standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html) if you want to implement something simple. You probably only need to implement the GET verb if you just wan't simple I/O. You could also look at implementing [JSON](http://www.json.org/) as a data interchange format. If you're looking for information on how to implement a TCP/IP server too, then there are [several books on the subject](http://store.elsevier.com/product.jsp?isbn=9780123745408).